# How can I run 2 sites on Apache? Complex situation

Tags: wordpress, apache, azure, dns, cname

**My goal is to host 2 different sites from the same VM and both on port 80.  One is a Wordpress site on domain.com and the other is a web-based app on app.domain.com.  If that can't be done, then my alternate goal is to get only the Wordpress site running on domain.com port 80.**

My registrar is 1and1.com and the DNS settings are like this (below).  Please note they don't allow a CNAME record for primary domain, only for subdomain.  Here is my A Record (IP address and domain names in this post are not my real ones):

> ```
>    Type: A Record   Value: 123.456.789.10
> ```

My host is Azure where I have a VM running with a Virtual IP address of 123.456.789.10.  This Azure VM has endpoints configured like this:

> ```
>    TCP    Public Port 8080    Private Port 8080
>    TCP    Public Port 80      Private Port 80
>    TCP    Public Port 2121    Private Port 21
>    TCP    Public Port 22      Private Port 22
> ```

On Azure I have a DNS Zone configured like this:

> ```
>     Name: www    Type: A    TTL: 3600    Value: 123.456.789.10
> ```

My apache default file is configured like this:

> ```
> # FOR WORDPRESS WEBSITE (DOMAIN.COM)
>       Listen 80
>       <VirtualHost *:80>
>       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
>       <Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress/">
>           AllowOverride All
>       </Directory>
>       </VirtualHost>          
>  # FOR APPLICATION (APP.DOMAIN.COM)
>       <VirtualHost *:80>
>       DocumentRoot /var/www/application/
>       <Directory "/var/www/application/">
>           AllowOverride All
>       </Directory>
>       </VirtualHost>
> ```

My .htaccess file in Wordpress root folder is configured like this:

> ```
>  # BEGIN WordPress
>     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
>     </IfModule>
>  # END WordPress
>     <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
>     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
>     </IfModule>
> ```

Wordpress config file:

> ```
>     It's totally standard and the site was running last week without 
>     issue while on port 8090, but I wanted to use port 80 instead.
> ```

Ubuntu hosts file:

> ```
>     127.0.0.1 localhost
>     ServerName domain.com
> # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
>     ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>     fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>     ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
>     ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>     ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
>     ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
> ```

Currently I'm getting an error message in the browser >> This site can’t be reached domain.com took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT but sometimes when tweaking my settings (above) I would get a directory listing in the browser which showed apache's default directory of /var/www

My feeling is that I need more A and CNAME records setup, but I don't know exactly how to configure them.  I've already spent 5 full days working on this and Googling solutions that didn't work for me.  Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0):

did you try ServerName? And adding that to the hosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/wordpress/error.log
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/application/
    ErrorLog /var/www/application/error.log
```

Comment: Yes I tried this and tried again just to be sure.  It doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Can you add the entry to the hosts file? Now you have only localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: I added the entry to my hosts file.  Now it shows the directory listing when I key the domain name in a browser.  But it's of course showing /var/www/ instead of /var/www/html/wordpress even though my Apache config file clearly gives the second path.  Also note I can't ping the virtual IP address from Ubuntu or from windows command prompt, although I can easily connect to that IP via SSH (port 22).

Comment: Please, paste the full config file with the hosts file somewhere, i.e., http://paste.org.ru. As far as i know, ICMP is still blocked (that's why you can't ping the VM)

Comment: Change ServerName to 127.0.0.1 (in the hosts file). I see no problem with the config yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Azure, but you will need to open up port 80 publicly - it looks like only 8080 is setup at the moment.

Also, you definitely need the:

```
ServerName
```

directives.

If you can provide your real domain name, we can check DNS/ports etc for you.

Comment: Also, I opened up port 80 publicly.

Comment: You should edit your question to show that - it's not listed in the 'endpoints' section. Port 80 is open, so you should at least be able to see an error from apache, if it's still not working?

Comment: OK I updated my question to reflect this.  To answer your question, no error, but I'm getting a directory listing (the wrong directory).  It's showing /var/www/ instead of /var/www/html/wordpress even though my Apache config file for this port number clearly gives the second path.  Help!

Comment: Is there a 'default' config file in your conf.d directory? Are you getting the same result for both host names?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!  This site was built from a copy of another site and I noticed that when I copied the contents of my Wordpress folder directly to /var/www/ the address bar wouldn't load the site BUT it would show domain.com:8090 (where "domain.com" is my new site and "8090" is the port number the old site previously used) in the address bar RELENTLESSLY even though this directive was NOT contained in my apache config file.  This gave me the idea that for some reason, some line of code is directing to this port.  So via phpmyadmin I altered the Wordpress "site name" and "url" values (which contained this port number) in my database to match my new domain with no port number and viola.  To me it doesn't make sense why this helped, but anyway the site then loaded up great!  But this was only half the problem because I shouldn't have to put my wordpress content directly in /var/www but instead anywhere I want.

The second half of the problem was solved when my coworker decided to copy over my file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default" to a new file "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf" for reasons I do not understand.  According to him this made apache actually start listening to my directives in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file, and so the gears start turning again.  To me this makes no sense because it contradicts other apache servers that I have running so I'll get clarification and post again if worthwhile.